# How to run unit tests using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyinstaller, python-unittest

I am using pyinstaller to bundle my python project. I also have some unit tests in my project and I was wondering if there is a way to run the unit tests before pyinstaller bundles everything together. Is it possible? Here is my spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
import os
import sys

a = Analysis(['src/hub/Driver.py'],
             pathex=['src'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='BiRadExtractor',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

do i need to add some command in the spec file to run the unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run unit tests before bundling your project with PyInstaller. You can create a build script that first runs the unit tests and only proceeds with the PyInstaller build if all tests pass.

Here's a sample setup assuming your project is correctly organised :

```
my_project/
|-- my_module/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- some_module.py
|-- tests/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_some_module.py
|-- main.py
|-- build.py
```

And here's a build.py script to achieve this:

```
import os
import unittest
import PyInstaller.__main__

version = '0.0.1'

def main():
    if run_tests():
        PyInstaller.__main__.run([
            'main.py',
            f'--name=MyAppName-v{version}',
            '--distpath=dist',
            f'--add-data=images/app.ico{os.pathsep}./images',
            f'--add-data=images/logo.png{os.pathsep}./images',
            '--clean',
            '--onefile',
            '--specpath=build',
            '--windowed',
            '--noconsole',
        ])
    else:
        print("Tests failed. Build aborted.")

def run_tests():
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = loader.discover('tests')
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    result = runner.run(suite)
    return result.wasSuccessful()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please remember to adjust the PyInstaller arguments (like --add-data) to fit your project.  I'm using this solution on a project I build in both Linux and Windows, sorry for the slow reply but hope it still helps.